# Multiply bested DIV, inner div full height with flexbox only - possible?

Tags: css, flexbox

i have a complex layout in which i have a div generated by JavaScript with dynamic height, he is called ".outer" . This div has some nested divs, finally leading to a div called ".target". I need the target div to be at ".outers" height. And i don't want to address the inner divs since they are varying markup generated by my JS Framework.

I do not want to set the height via JS, i can not set position to absolute nor relative in ".outer"

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="anotherInner">
      <div class="target">
        This div should be outer's height no matter how many divs are between target and outer like ".inner"
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

.outer {
  background: #333;
  height: 500px;  /* this is not a pixel value, only for example*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.inner {
  background: #555;
}

.target {
  background: #777;
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

Example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akwWZK?editors=1100

Comment: Not possible using flexbox. Flexbox works only on `display:flex` parent and the immediate children. Best bet is to use `position: relative` to `.outer` and `position: absolute` to `.inner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way to do this in FlexBox is to address the .inner div's in your CSS by adding display: flex; to them.

I've created a working example for you here: http://codepen.io/mattpark22/pen/rLwwZp

To '.inner' add:

```
display: flex;
```

To '.target' add:

```
height: 100%;
```

To '.outer' change, flex-direction to:

```
flex-direction: row;
```

My codepen example also cleans up some CSS which isn't required.

Comment: If this an acceptable solution to your question, please can you mark this as the accepted answer. Thank you.